# Swept AABB for 3d collisions

Tags: collision-detection, physics-engine, aabb

https://www.gamedev.net/tutorials/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/swept-aabb-collision-detection-and-response-r3084/

So I was following the tutorial above to implement swept aabb for collision detection, and so far I think I have managed to successfully translate the code to 3D.

[image]

However, I'm not super how to translate this part of the code (above) to 3 dimensions. If anyone would be willing to provide an explanation it would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Also, since my game is in 3d, I would need to run my collision detection 3 times right? Once for each direction it can slide?